# Does the weak generator of a Markov semigroup admit an adjoint operator?

Tags: functional-analysis, stochastic-processes, operator-theory, markov-process, semigroup-of-operators

Let

- $(E,\mathcal E)$ be a measurable space
- $\mathcal E_b$ denote the set of all bounded $\mathcal E$-measurable $f:E\to\mathbb R$
- $\lambda$ be a $\sigma$-finite measure on $(E,\mathcal E)$.

If $p,q\in[1,\infty]$ with $\frac1p+\frac1q=1$, then $$\langle f,g\rangle:=\int fg\:{\rm d}\lambda$$ for $f\in\mathcal L^p(\lambda)$ and $g\in\mathcal L^q(\lambda)$.

Now let $(\kappa_t)_{t\ge0}$ be a Markov semigroup on $(E,\mathcal E)$ and, as usual, $$(\kappa_tf)(x):=\int\kappa_t(x,{\rm d}y)f(y)\;\;\;\text{for }x\in E,f\in\mathcal E_b\text{ and }t\ge0.$$ We can define a linear operator $(\mathcal D(A),A)$ via $$\mathcal D(A):=\left\{f\in\mathcal E_b\mid\exists g\in\mathcal E_b:\forall x\in E:\frac{(\kappa_tf)(x)-f(x)}t\xrightarrow{t\to0+}g(x)\right\}$$ and $$(Af)(x):=\frac{(\kappa_tf)(x)-f(x)}t\xrightarrow{t\to0+}g(x)\;\;\;\text{for }x\in E\text{ and }f\in\mathcal E_b.$$

> Is it possible to show that $A$ (considered as an unbounded operator from $\mathcal E_b$ to $L^1(\lambda)$) has an adjoint operator $A^\ast$ with respect to $\langle\;\cdot\;,\;\cdot\;\rangle$, i.e. $$\langle Af,g\rangle=\langle f,A^\ast g\rangle\tag2$$ for all $f\in\mathcal D(A)$ and $g\in\mathcal D(A^\ast)$?

$\mathcal D(A^\ast)$ should clearly be a subspace of $\mathcal L^1(\lambda)$. But what is $\mathcal D(A^\ast)$ precisely and how can we guarantee exisgtence of $A^\ast$?

**EDIT**: My guess is $$\mathcal D(A^\ast)=\{g\in\mathcal L^1(\lambda)\mid\exists f^\ast\in\mathcal L^1(\lambda):\forall f\in\mathcal D(A):\langle Af,g\rangle=\langle f,f^\ast\rangle\}\tag3.$$

Comment: @MaoWao I'm not sure whether this actually a weaker condition, but I think we need to assume less: Let $C\subseteq\mathcal E_b$ be separating for the space of finite signed measures on $(E,\mathcal E)$. We then easily see that if $f\in\mathcal L^1(\lambda)$ with $\int fg\:{\rm d}\lambda=0$ for all $g\in C$, then $f=0$ $\lambda$-a.e.. Now let $B$ be any linear operator on $\mathcal E_b$ with $C\subseteq\overline{\mathcal D(B)}$.

Comment: @MaoWao Now define $$\mathcal D(B^\ast)=\{g\in\mathcal L^1(\lambda)\mid\exists g^\ast\in L^1(\lambda):\forall f\in\mathcal D(B):\langle Bf,g\rangle=\langle f,g^\ast\rangle\}\tag4$$ and $B^\ast:=g^\ast$. By the former result, this is a well-defined linear operator from $\mathcal L^1(\lambda)$ to $L^1(\lambda)$. (please note that I've replaced $g^\ast\in\mathcal L^1(\lambda)$ by $g^\ast\in L^1(\lambda)$).

Comment: @MaoWao Regarding the usual definition of the adjoint of a bounded linear operator $C$ between normed (or locally convex) spaces $X$ and $Y$: Isn't the adjoint of such an operator usually defined to be $$C:Y'\to X'\;,\;\;\;\varphi\mapsto\varphi\circ C?$$ How is this related to $(4)$?